# What type of MOSFET can be controlled by an Arduino PWM output?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pwm

I'm looking for a MOSFET that can be used controlled by an Arduino output that increases and decreases in voltage. I need to control a bright LED that needs 5V. The PWM output on the Arduino doesn't output enough, so I will use a MOSFET as shown in the image:

[image: schematic]

I don't know which type will be suited for my project. Where can I maybe find one in everyday equipment?

Comment: The arudino diagram shows no power connections so it will not work. Also you are missing some sort of current limit for the LED. You show a device that is manufactured using a NMOS process, what is it? A simple schematic is much better than an arudino diagram. Posting a schematic would help along with links to technical information on all the hardware devices, power supplies etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need (for predictable results) a logic-level MOSFET. One that has a specified Rds(on) with 4.5V or 5V drive (or lower is okay too), assuming an Arduino that has 5V nominal outputs. Eg. [IRLZ44](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91328/sihlz44.pdf).

> • Logic-Level Gate Drive
>
> • RDS(on) Specified at VGS = 4 V and 5 V

You also should have a series resistor on the LED.

You can look up datasheets for most parts that you can salvage and see if they meet those requirements.

Comment: What would you recomment for 12-24V?

Comment: @DavidGrean Specific product recommendations are OT here, but LRLZ44 is okay. Newer SMT parts are cheaper and better performing. I might use an AO3400 (SOT-23).